# How to horizontally align two DIV

Tags: css, css-float, vertical-alignment

i have this snipet of code and i want to align the **variation-options** options with the **woo-price-area** on the right:

```
        <div class="woo-button-area">

            <div class="variations variation-price-wrap">
                <div class="variation-options">
                    <select id="opt" class="" name="attribute_pa_opt" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_opt"
                            data-show_option_none="no">
                        <option value="opt1" class="attached enabled">Option 1</option>
                        <option value="op2" class="attached enabled">Option 2</option>
                    </select></div>
                <div class="woo-price-area">
                    <p class="price">
                        <del><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span
                                        class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>9.00</span></del>
                        <ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span
                                        class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>5.00</span></ins>
                    </p>
                    <div class="wc-availability"></div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="single_variation_wrap">
                <div class="woocommerce-variation single_variation" style="">
                    <div class="font80">
                        <a rel="nofollow" href="#details" class="csspopuptrigger" data-popup="details">Details</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="prosconswidget">
                        <div class="wpsm_pros mt20 font80">
                            <ul>
                                <li>Test li</li>
                            </ul>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have tried floating but the **details** link come over price area.

This is the page url: https://jsfiddle.net/4x93rLmf/21/

Comment: Show me the actual page. I will give you the right code.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4x93rLmf/21/

Comment: @MoradAngel if thats what you want plz dont forget to accept the answer

Comment: you can try to add line-height:12px or 16px maybe it will fix it

Comment: You should re-publish your deleted question as I can answer it, if you like: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62759419/3730754

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can target their wrapper class `.variations.variation-price-wrap{display:flex;}`

```css
.variations.variation-price-wrap{display:flex;  
                                 justify-content:space-between;}
p.price {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="woo-button-area">

            <div class="variations variation-price-wrap">
                <div class="variation-options">
                    <select id="opt" class="" name="attribute_pa_opt" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_opt"
                            data-show_option_none="no">
                        <option value="opt1" class="attached enabled">Option 1</option>
                        <option value="op2" class="attached enabled">Option 2</option>
                    </select></div>
                <div class="woo-price-area">
                    <p class="price">
                        <del><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span
                                        class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>9.00</span></del>
                        <ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span
                                        class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>5.00</span></ins>
                    </p>
                    <div class="wc-availability"></div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="single_variation_wrap">
                <div class="woocommerce-variation single_variation" style="">
                    <div class="font80">
                        <a rel="nofollow" href="#details" class="csspopuptrigger" data-popup="details">Details</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="prosconswidget">
                        <div class="wpsm_pros mt20 font80">
                            <ul>
                                <li>Test li</li>
                            </ul>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: is aligned but the price isnt in the right, also the real price 9 should be under 5 and all floating right

Comment: plz check the updates and tell me if thats what you want

Comment: no the select option should be in the left and price in the right

Comment: how i can i get the css ? i see run code snippet but where is the css code ?

Comment: its before the html is that what you want?

Comment: there is a little problem the price isnt aligned perfectlly withe the select options there is some space in the top of price